# How to get average of only certain rows in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with 5 column and N rows. A row is added when a team changes size.

Column A is "Team Size at Start"
Column B is "Team Size at End"
Column C is "Velocity in Sprint N"
Column D is "Velocity in Sprint N+1"
Column E is "Velocity in Sprint N+2"

```
Row | A | B  | C  | D  | E (end row)
1   | 5 | 6  | 20 | 15 | 25 (end row)
2   | 4 | 7  | 10 | 8  | 15 (end row)
3   | 5 | 6  | 20 | 15 | 25 (end row)
4   | 4 | 7  | 15 | 12 | 18 (end row)
5   | 9 | 11 | 25 | 20 | 30 (end row)
```

I'm looking for a way to calculate the AVERAGE of column C, the AVERAGE of column D, and the AVERAGE of column E, but only when the values of columns A and B match in a row.

For example, I would want:

Averages for C, D, and E for rows 1 and 3, because Col A = Col B.
Averages for C, D, and E for rows 2 and 4, because Col A = Col B.
Averages for C, D, and E for row 5, because no other rows match Col A and B.

Comment: where do you want this data stored, is it in another table that lists the unique pairs from A and B?

Comment: @pnuts The example does not match the description. All what is needed is to average group by column A and B.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a fairly straightforward implementation of the [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-4CCA2550-DAB3-41C4-BCD2-648E17F20553) if it can be reasonably assumed that you have Excel version 2007 or higher.

[image: AVERAGEIFS two column match]

The formula in G1 is,

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1, $A1)=COUNTIF($A:$A, $A1), COUNTIF($B$1:$B1, $B1)=COUNTIF($B:$B, $B1)), AVERAGEIFS(C:C,$A:$A, $A1,$B:$B, $B1), "")
```

Fill both right and down. I've added a condition where only the last occurrence of the matches displays the average. Remove that portion of it doesn't suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

if:

> column F becomes the average of column C,
>
> column G becomes the average of column D,
>
> column H becomes the average of column E,

paste this formula in F1 then copy it to all rows in F,G,H

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C:C,$A:$A,"="&$A1,$B:$B,"="&$B1)
```

Comment: Calum, thanks. I got this to work perfectly. It's not the solution I originally envisioned (because the averages are repeated), but it works well and it's easy to understand.

Should I ask a separate question if I now want to color-code the matching rows?

Comment: @user3221570 yes, a seperate question, also if one of the answers worked for you, suggest you accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table with column A and B as row headers, the rest of the columns as values aggregated as average. You may want to select the classic view for the pivot table.

Comment: Sorry my table was a slight mis-match because I numbered the rows. Corrected below:

A   | B  | C    | D   | E   (end row)
5   | 6   | 20  | 15  | 25 (end row) - Team went from 5 ppl to 6 ppl
4   | 7   | 10  | 8    | 15 (end row)
5   | 6   | 20  | 15  | 25 (end row) - Team went from 5 ppl to 6 ppl
4   | 7   | 15  | 12  | 18 (end row)
9   | 11 | 25  | 20  | 30 (end row)

Comment: Did you try the proposed solution?

Comment: Works perfectly. I just need a way to color-code all the matching rows. There will be N row matches (where cols A and B match), so I'm not sure how to apply conditional formatting for this. I would need every combination to be a different color.

Comment: You can drop onevof the values again but instead of averaging, use count. The rows that have a match will have a count > 1. You can use that to color code.